# Mahout lucene/solr compatibility

Tags: solr, lucene, version, mahout

I'm trying to use Mahout clustering to cluster my solr index. I am using Solr 5.5 and latest Mahout version only supports 4.6.1 lucene indexes therefore I'm getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main"rg.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException: Format version is not supported
```

So my question is can someone help me with how to safely update lucene version that is being used by mahout

Comment: So, your question is how can you use Mahout with a newer Lucene version that it supports?  I'm pretty sure you can't.

Comment: Yes or even rebuild mahout from source but it doesn't seem to be working :(

Comment: Of course not, it doesn't support it.  Mahout doesn't support Lucene 5.x.  Last I saw, this was marked as [Won't Fix](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1650).